# Uncaught ReferenceError: revslider_showDoubleJqueryError is not defined at onLoad (nile-slider.js:45)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use a theme for my Angular 7 Project Landing Page. I observed that the slider is not working. So when I inspected the Page and checked console, I got this error:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: revslider_showDoubleJqueryError is not defined
at onLoad (nile-slider.js:45)
at nile-slider.js:37
at nile-slider.js:82
```

[image: uncaught_error]

Then when I opened the source, I got this:

[image: uncaught_error_source]

See it below:

```js
var revapi3,
    tpj;
(function () {
    if (!/loaded|interactive|complete/.test(document.readyState)) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
    else onLoad();

    function onLoad() {
        if (tpj === undefined) {
            tpj = jQuery;
            if ("off" == "on") tpj.noConflict();
        }
        if (tpj("#rev_slider_3_1").revolution == undefined) {
            revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_3_1");
        } else {
            revapi3 = tpj("#rev_slider_3_1").show().revolution({
                sliderType: "standard",
                jsFileLocation: "//localhost/slider/revslider/public/assets/js/",
                sliderLayout: "fullwidth",
                dottedOverlay: "none",
                delay: 9000,
                navigation: {
                    onHoverStop: "off",
                },
                responsiveLevels: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
                visibilityLevels: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
                gridwidth: [1120, 1024, 778, 480],
                gridheight: [868, 768, 960, 720],
                lazyType: "none",
                shadow: 0,
                spinner: "spinner0",
                stopLoop: "off",
                stopAfterLoops: -1,
                stopAtSlide: -1,
                shuffle: "off",
                autoHeight: "off",
                disableProgressBar: "on",
                hideThumbsOnMobile: "off",
                hideSliderAtLimit: 0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,
                debugMode: false,
                fallbacks: {
                    simplifyAll: "off",
                    nextSlideOnWindowFocus: "off",
                    disableFocusListener: false,
                }
            });
        }; /* END OF revapi call */
    }; /* END OF ON LOAD FUNCTION */
}()); /* END OF WRAPPING FUNCTION */
```

**landing-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
```

enableProdMode();

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-landing-page',
 templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
 // styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.scss']
 styleUrls: [
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/animate.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/owl.carousel.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/owl.theme.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/hover-min.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/flag-icon.min.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/style.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/css/elegant_icon.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/rslider/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/rslider/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
          '../../../assets/landing_page/rslider/css/settings.css'
        ]
})

export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

**landing-page.component.html**

```html
    <!-- jquery library  -->

    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/nile-slider.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'"></i>
    <!-- REVOLUTION JS FILES -->
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js'"></i>
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 5.0 EXTENSIONS -->
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/YouTubePopUp.jquery.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/owl.carousel.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/imagesloaded.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/custom.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/popper.min.js'"></i>
    <i let [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/bootstrap.min.js'"></i>
```

Please how do I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This means that jquery.js and/or the revslider-related javascripts are **not** loaded as this is a functionality defined in there.

A possible cause is that revslider-related folders (*assets* and *revolution* with their subfolders) are not accessible for your wewbserver.
By default, the zip contains these folders with rights like
`drwx------@`
So solution can be:
`chmod -R 755 <yourFolderThatContainsRevSlider>`

The answer is quite late, but hopefully helpful for someone else.